# How do I use Docker on BitBucket pipelines to test a Django app that needs PostGIS?

Tags: python, django, docker, bitbucket, postgis

I'm trying to build automated testing on Django app on a private BitBucket repo, using BitBucket pipelines.

I have all the tests in place, and they can be run using `./manage.py test` or using `tox`. This works fine locally, where the tests build a (temporary) PostGIS test database. PostGIS and stuff like gdal is necessary for all the `requirementst.txt` to properly install.

I'm having problems finding a Docker image that gives me a full Python + PostGIS/gdal etc stack on Docker, and I lack the skills to build it myself.

My failed attemps are documented on GitHub:
https://github.com/zostera/docker-django-ci

Can someone point me in the right direction (tutorial) or perhaps help me out with a working example?

Comment: Pipelines seems quite limited at the moment in this respect - other CI services generally support external services (postgres, elasticsearch, redis etc.) that you can use from your tests. BB _seems_ to rely on you baking them into your Docker image, which seems like an anti-pattern (to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have recently figured it out, and published our own Docker image with support for Python, Django, Postgres, PotGIS and a few other things.

https://github.com/zostera/docker-django-ci

Answer (score 1):

I've written a detailed post about [Building, Testing and Deploying Django App with Bitbucket Pipelines](https://blog.revolucija.hr/building-testing-and-deploying-django-app-with-bitbucket-pipelines-32868e12a472#.fbheycrx5)

It can be a good start for extending it with PostGIS and I will point you in the right direction. In addition to the post, we've open sourced [Dockerfiles](https://bitbucket.org/revolucija/dockerfiles) which you can extend to support PostGIS.

You'll need a good tutorial on installing PostGIS, e.g. try [this one](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html#PostGIS).

Start with the `centos7-postgresql9.4` Dockerfile, and add commands for installing PostGIS, right before `VOLUME` line:

```
...

# install PostGIS
RUN yum -y install postgis2_94 postgis2_94-client

VOLUME ["/var/lib/pgsql/9.4"]
```

Finally, you have to enable extensions in database. Add this code to `start_postgres.sh`:

```
if [ -n "${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}" ]; then
  echo "Creating database \"${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}\"..."
  sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE \"${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}\" OWNER \"${POSTGRESQL_USER}\";"
  # create db gistest, connect to db gistest and create postgis extension
  sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE gistest;\c gistest;CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
fi
```